# How to make Gradle 7 preserve dependency lock status in a single file

Tags: java, gradle

Gradle generates a dependency lock file for each subproject in a multi-module project. Those lock files have a lot of duplicate dependencies. Is there a way to preserve the lock status in a single lock file under the root project?

Comment: Have you found an answer? I am struggling with this too. Lockfile per module seems redundant to me.

Answer (score -1):

The lock files are for internal use by gradle. I wouldn't recommend touching them to be honest. They have the lock files to save some infos about the dependencies. If you have the same dependency in multiple sub-projects you could try adding those to the root project gradle file ;)